# Is Wagtail's InlinePanel Compatible w/ a Non Page Model?

Tags: wagtail

I have a wagtail non-Page model that I'd like to use an `InlinePanel` for so that I can edit multiple items inline in the parent form.

```
class Parent(ClusterableModel):
   panels = [...,
        InlinePanel('child_items')
   ]

class Child(Orderable):
   value = models...
   parent_value = ParentalKey('.Parent', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='child_items')
```

But unfortunately the inline panel is not rendering in the wagtail admin UI.

From a quick glance at the code it seems like the `InlinePanel` requires a Page object/editor, so I thought I'd ask here if there is a way to use an `InlinePanel` on a non-Page object, or if there is a better way to achieve inline editing of objects (like django's `StackedInline`) in the wagtail admin for non-page objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`InlinePanel` does work on non-Page models if they are registered as snippets or through ModelAdmin. A working version of your code is (tested on a newly-created Wagtail project with `home/models.py` replaced with the code below):

```
from django.db import models
from modelcluster.fields import ParentalKey
from modelcluster.models import ClusterableModel

from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel, InlinePanel
from wagtail.core.models import Page, Orderable
from wagtail.snippets.models import register_snippet

class HomePage(Page):
    pass


@register_snippet
class Parent(ClusterableModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    panels = [
        FieldPanel('title'),
        InlinePanel('child_items', label='Child items'),
    ]

class Child(Orderable):
    parent_value = ParentalKey(Parent, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='child_items')
    value = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('value'),
    ]
```

Comment: I very much missed out on the concept of snippits, which is the key - thank you!

Comment: Is there a way to do this without the `register_snippet`? I am getting an error: "Unknown field(s) (title) specified", but the model shouldn't have a "title" field.

Comment: @BrylieChristopherOxley Snippets don't require a `title` field (although you probably do want to define a `__str__` method so that there's something meaningful to show in listings). Perhaps you left in the `FieldPanel('title')` line from the above example?

Comment: None of the relevant models in my project had a title, nor did I copy and paste the code above. I only got the error after adding the `register_snippet` decorator. I will try to reproduce the issue.

Comment: OK, the snippet approach works. However, now I have a snippets menu showing ecommerce orders. Is there a way to do this without registering it as a snippet, or at least to hide it from the Snippets menu?

Comment: @BrylieChristopherOxley you can hide it from the Snippets menu using a callback in the `wagtail_hooks.py` file. This example hides the entire snippets menu. We hide the whole snippets menus and add the snippets of interest directly to the main menu.

`@hooks.register("construct_main_menu")
def hide_snippets_menu_item(request, menu_items):
    """Hide generic "Snippets" link in sidebar."""
    menu_items[:] = [item for item in menu_items if item.name != "snippets"]`